# Breaking apart sentence with pointers leads to a seg fault

Tags: c, pointers

I want to break a sentence into words using pointers.

I wrote some code but I am really confused because I get segmentation fault.
kindly help me out.
Thanks in advance.

```
char **breakstring(char *str)
{
    char **temp=(char **)malloc(5*sizeof(char *));
    char **temp_store = temp;
    while((*str) != '/0')
    {
      while((*str != '\0') && *str!=' ')
      {
      **temp=*str;
      **temp++;
      *str++;
      }

      str++;
      temp++;
    }
    return temp_store;
}

int main()
{
    char **arra;
    char *arr="this is a stupid string";
    arra=breakstring(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At what line is the segfault occuring?

Comment: it compiled with a warning bellow.<br>
test.c: In function ‘breakstring’:<br>
test.c:19:22: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]<br>
when I try debug  using gdb. and run it give the following error.<br>
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.<br>
0x000000000040051e in breakstring ()

Comment: There are several problems in this code, among them:  only mallocing enough space for two words (when your test string has 5), and nesting your `while` loops such that the end-of-string check is only checked after a space is encountered.

Comment: I think you have a problem with your dereferencing `**temp=*str;` line, etc. Your malloc statement allocates two pointers to char pointers, however, they do not point to anything. You cannot dereference them until they have been initialized.

Comment: what is the function supposed to do exactly? add that information to the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char **temp=(char **)malloc(2*sizeof(char *));
```

You allocated 2 pointers.  Your input string has more than 2 spaces.  If you still want to use dynamic memory, you'll have to periodically call `realloc` to ask for more space, or possibly introduce some other arbitrary maximum that's greater than 2.

```
  while(*str!=' ')
  {
**temp=*str;
**temp++;
*str++;
  }
```

What this says is "while the current char of the string is not a space, add the string to `temp`, and advance.  So if you're called with `"This is a ..."` you'll end up with `"This is a ..."`, `"his is a ..."`, `"is is a ..."`, etc.  Inside this loop you want to advance `str` without assigning to `temp`.  (You'll also want to add the condition `*str`, i.e. `while (*str && *str != ' ')`)   Outside the loop you'll want something like `*temp++ = str;`, then skip all the space characters.  (You might also want to add a `NUL` terminator to stop the string, but you've called the function with a `const char *` string literal, so to maintain that you'd probably have to copy the whole string onto the heap.)

All in all, the amount of heap allocations we're leading into here is somewhat un-C-like for string manipulation.  I suggest instead of returning a heap allocation and passing constant strings, you look into an interface like `strsep()` (the better version of the ugly `strtok()`), which modifies the caller's buffer.

*Update:* @Rohan is also right about the return value issue.  If you keep doing `temp++` you need to remember the original position of the start of the allocation, and return that.  Although, I would re-iterate looking into `strsep` or `strtok_r`.

Comment: Sorry for the language.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

There are few of issues:

With this line:

```
char **temp=(char **)malloc(2*sizeof(char *));
```

you are able to store only 2 words as you are allocating memory for only 2 `char *` pointers. But you are actually storing more than that.

Your inner `while` loop while try to read invalid memory when you trying for last word as it will try to find `' '` space, but it would have been terminated by `'\0'`.

```
while(*str!=' ')
{
   **temp=*str;
   **temp++;
   *str++;
}
```

update it to:

```
while((*str != '\0') && *str!=' ')
{
   **temp=*str;
   **temp++;
   *str++;
}
```

Third, you are returning updated `temp` pointer. i.e it has been incremented and changed to point to last word. Instead you need to return the original value of `temp`.
You can do this:

```
char **breakstring(char *str)
{
    char **temp=(char **)malloc(2*sizeof(char *));
    char **temp_store = temp;
    while((*str) != '/0')
    ....
    return temp_store;
}
```